# logrotate for /var/log/cron not working?

Tags: cron, logrotate

Hi i have added the following lines in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng to make /var/log/cron rotate.

```
/var/log/cron {
   rotate 1
   size=1k
   nocompress
   postrotate
     /bin/killall -HUP syslog-ng 2>/dev/null || true
   endscript
}
```

After i do this, it is found that logrotation for /var/log/cron is not happening. Moreover the logrotation for other files which used to work earlier before adding this piece of code also does not work. I have included the file /etc/logrotate.d/ in /etc/logrotate.conf

Where am i going wrong ?

My original /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng is given below

```
/var/log/cmm/cmm/error.log {
    rotate 5
    compress
    size=100k
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslog-ng 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}

# ------------------- rotate and move user.log
/usr/local/data/log/user.log {
   rotate 10
   compress
   size=1000k
   missingok
}

/tmp/log/user.log {
   rotate 1
   nocompress
   size=100k
   postrotate
       /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslog-ng 2> /dev/null || true
       cat /tmp/log/user.log.1 >> /usr/local/data/log/user.log
   endscript

}

# ------------------- rotate and move debug.log
/usr/local/data/log/debug.log {
   rotate 32
   compress
   size=1000k
   missingok
}

/tmp/log/debug.log {
   rotate 1
   nocompress
   size=100k
   postrotate
       /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslog-ng 2> /dev/null || true
       cat /tmp/log/debug.log.1 >> /usr/local/data/log/debug.log
   endscript
}
```

Comment: You are missing the "postrotate" and "endscript" directives.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the postrotae and endscript directive. Actually it is there in my code. Then also the logrotation is not happening

Answer (score 3):

All your other directives have `/usr/bin/killall`.

The `cron` directive has `/bin/killall`.  Maybe that's the reason?

In any case, run

```
logrotate -d /path/to/your/script
```

And look for clues in its output.